# reading analog pins on Beagle bone Black

Tags: javascript

I am reading 3 analog ports simultaneously on BeagleBoneBlack. After 15 iterations, it gives the following error-

```
fs.js:381
  var r = binding.read(fd, buffer, offset, length, position);
                  ^
Error: EAGAIN, no more processes
    at Object.fs.readSync (fs.js:381:19)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:208:28)
    at Object.f.analogRead (/usr/lib/node_modules/bonescript/index.js:397:28)
    at Timer.cal (/var/lib/cloud9/Untitled2:15:15)
    at Timer.exports.setInterval.timer.ontimeout (timers.js:234:14)
```

How can I remove this error?

Comment: You probably should add some more details, esp. on how you are reading.

Comment: We have forked bone script and created new, improved and bug free version of the same named octalbonescript. You can get it here: https://www.npmjs.org/package/octalbonescript